# magma_dpotrf_gpu gives segmentation fault

Tags: cuda, lapack, magma, cblas

I have a cblas and lapack code that I'm trying to "convert" to magma code to take advantage of the GPU.
This is my CPU code that works fine:

```
cblas_dsyrk(CblasColMajor,CblasUpper,CblasTrans,n,m,1.0,A2,m, 0.0,C_theta,n);
cblas_dsyrk(CblasColMajor,CblasUpper,CblasTrans,n,m,1.0,A1,m,-1.0,C_theta,n);
clapack_dpotrf(CblasColMajor,CblasUpper,n,C_theta,n);
```

Now, for the magma GPU version, I did this:

```
magma_dmalloc(&d_A1, m*n);
magma_dmalloc(&d_A2, m*n);
magma_dmalloc(&d_C_theta, n*n);

magma_dsetmatrix(m ,n, A1, m, d_A1, m, queue);
magma_dsetmatrix(m ,n, A2, m, d_A2, m, queue);
magma_dsetmatrix(n ,n, C_theta, n, d_C_theta, n, queue);

magma_dsyrk(MagmaUpper, MagmaTrans, n, m, 1.0, d_A2, m, 0.0, d_C_theta, n, queue);
magma_dsyrk(MagmaUpper, MagmaTrans, n, m, 1.0, d_A1, m, -1.0, d_C_theta, n, queue);
magma_int_t *info_potrf; 
magma_dpotrf_gpu(MagmaUpper, n, d_C_theta, n, info_potrf);
```

And for some reason, the last line is giving segmentation fault. What am I doing wrong here? It all seems correct.

Comment: you need to have a memory allocation backing that `info_potrf` pointer.  Instead do `magma_int_t info_potrf;`  (i.e. remove the asterisk)  and on the last line change `info_potrf` to `&info_potrf`

Comment: Thanks @RobertCrovella! I figured it out now. I came here to answer my own question and saw your answer. It is precisely that! I was worried with something possibly wrong on dsyrk and the problem was a lot easier. Many thanks Robert!

Comment: @thejoker: please answer this yourself so it can get off the unanswered queue

Comment: Done @talonmies. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The solution was answered by @RobertCrovella.

The asterisk needs to be removed in order to allocate memory for `info_potrf` variable, and on the second line, `&` needs to be added to use the variable address.
This is the correct way:

```
magma_int_t info_potrf; 
magma_dpotrf_gpu(MagmaUpper, n, d_C_theta, n, &info_potrf);
```

Comment: That isn't an answer. Please explain what you did to solve the problem. Then I will happily upvote it

Comment: It's fixed @talonmies

Comment: Thank you. That is much more useful